# How can same application hosted on two different servers( environments) share the single ASPState database?

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-2012, aspstate

I have a asp.net mvc 2 application hosted on two different web servers (Staging and Demo servers).In both the servers the application is hosted as Default Web Site. Now for both the webservers we are using two different custom databases(StaginDB, DemoDB) hosted on same database server.

1.WebServer 1 is using StagingDB and ASPStateDB
2.WebServer 2 is using DemoDB and ASPStateDB

Please find the screenshot for more details.
[image]

Based on the above diagram I want to know whether it is possible to share the same ASPStateDB across both the web servers(WebServer 1, WebServer 2). Will there be any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to mimic the scenario mentioned above, I created a POC application and configured ASPState database and my local development copy has already setup with ASPState database. My local development has single copy of ASPState database. I ran the application and found that there are two entries in the table: ASPStateTempApplications each pointing to individual applications. This confirmed that the configuration mentioned above will work too.